# Load 100 CSV files with a total size of 12GB in python memory faster than my code

Tags: python, csv

I have 100 .csv files, each one ranging from 50 to 800MBs. I am using this code to load them in memory:

```
import csv
import os
import time

mylist = []
start = time.time()
for csv_file in sorted(os.listdir('myfolder')):
    with open('myfolder' + csv_file, "r") as inputfile:
        data = csv.reader(inputfile)
        for row in data:
            mylist.append(row[1])

print("elapsed {}".format(time.time()-start))
```

With this code it takes 156 seconds on a Mac Air M1. This is quite problematic for me, as I plan to run many test scenarios with these data and for each scenario I have to wait for the data to be loaded. Is there some technique or library (pandas?) that I can leverage to speed up the memory loading?

Comment: The bottleneck here is almost certainly the I/O

Comment: watch this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEEhzQoKtQU&t=1902s)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is there a way to keep the list in memory, while I write various test scenarios? Keep the memory but change the code sort of thing

Comment: What's in the CSVs? How do the first few lines look? What calculations or analysis are you planning to do? Can you load the data into memory and hold it there then service requests/queries against it submitted via HTTP or sockets or MQTT rather than exiting and reloading?

Comment: Have one loading sequence and run many tests against the in-memory values? As long as you're not modifying the CSVs themselves there's no reason they need to go away.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel i don't know the code of the tests beforehand

Comment: Sounds homeworky. Alternatively convert your CSVs to a faster format to read if you absolutely have to read them every time you run. sqlite comes to mind.

Comment: it's not homeworky, if you mean teacher assigning task as part of a class.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, I pick only a certain value from each row (`row[1]`). I thought to store the `mylist` array to a `mylist.json` file and then load that file instead everytime. Loading the `mylist.json` file takes 35 seconds as opposed to 156 from the original code. Still slow, but progress